Error resolving plugin version conflict in Gradle: com.android.application version mismatch
I'm encountering the following error while building my Android project:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/macbook/StudioProjects/sellar_solarclue/android/app/build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.4.2', apply: false]
> The request for this plugin could not be satisfied because the plugin is already on the classpath with a different version (7.3.0).

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

The error suggests that the plugin version 7.4.2 conflicts with 7.3.0 that's already on the classpath. I'm unsure how to resolve this conflict.
Things I've tried:
Checking the build.gradle files for version mismatches.
Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
Updating Gradle to the latest version.
What did you try?
I checked the build.gradle files for any version mismatches between the plugin and dependencies.
I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it using ./gradlew clean and rebuilding from Android Studio.
I updated both the Gradle wrapper and Android Gradle plugin to the latest versions to resolve any potential compatibility issues.
I checked for any other places where the conflicting version might be declared in my project.
What were you expecting?
I expected the build process to complete successfully after resolving the version conflict between the com.android.application plugin versions (7.4.2 and 7.3.0). I was hoping that either upgrading all dependencies to the latest compatible versions or forcing a consistent version would fix the issue and allow the build to proceed.


In your project Open your libs.versions.toml files

Search com.android.application, you will get like this
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }


remove if duplicate there in the [plugins] Section


